# Don't destroy surfaceview onpause

Tags: android, resources, surfaceview

I'm using OGRE3d in my android app. When I'm press "home" btn surface will be destroyed.
It's what android usually do, but it's lead to some problems: i need to reinitialize native window(it's not so easy), I need to be extremely careful with all cases when the window can be destroyed and it can lead to some bugs. So, is there any way to destroy surface only on close the app?